# (PHP) $_POST + cURL + multi array

Tags: php, curl, multidimensional-array, http-post, array-push

I try to send a multi array via `cURL` but I can't find a nice way to do it.

My code example:

```
$data = array( 'a' => 'testa', 'b' => 'testb', 'c[d]' => 'test1', 'c[e]' => 'test2' );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

This will work and give the result I want on the `curl_init()` site:

`print_r( $_POST )` :

```
Array (

    [a] => testa
    [b] => testb
    [c] => Array (

            [d] => test1
            [e] => test2
    )
)
```

I'd like to add the c array dynamically like:

```
$c['d'] = 'test1';
$c['e'] = 'test2';
```

But if I try to add an array with `array_push` or `[]` I always get and (string)Array in the Array without data.

Can anyone help me to do it?

The whole code for faster testing:

```
$url = 'url_to_test.php';
$data = array( 'a' => 'testa', 'b' => 'testb', 'c[d]' => 'test1', 'c[e]' => 'test2' );
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$buffer = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo $buffer;
```

The test.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Thanks for any help!

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
$data = array( 'a' => 'testa', 'b' => 'testb', 'c[d]' => 'test1', 'c[e]' => 'test2' )
```

You've simply added new string keys "c[d]" and "c[e]".

If you want a nested array, use:

```
$data = array( 'a' => 'testa', 'b' => 'testb', 'c' => 
    array( 'd' => 'test1', 'e' => 'test2' )
)
```

-- EDIT --

You're trying to set POST data, which is essentially a set of key value pairs. You can't provide a nested array. You could, however, serialize the nested array and decode it at the other end. Eg:

```
$post_data = array('data' => serialize($data));
```

And at the receiving end:

```
$data = unserialize($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: yep and the result is the array string: Array
(
    [a] => testa
    [b] => testb
    [c] => Array
) I cant access the c array

Comment: Ah, the POST data has to be key value pairs, it won't take nested array. will edit.

Comment: Ive tried it with serialize but with unserialize I get a false back which means 'In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued.' This is the string before I try to unserialize: a:3:{s:1:\"a\";s:5:\"testa\";s:1:\"b\";s:5:\"testb\";s:1:\"c\";a:2:{s:1:\"d\";s:5:\"test1\";s:1:\"e\";s:5:\"test2\";}}

Comment: Ok found my problem.... need to stripslashes otherwise it can't get unserialize: $data = unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
$urltopost = "http://example.com/webservice/service.php";
$datatopost = array (0 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),1 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),2 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),3 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'));
$post_data = array('data' => serialize($datatopost));

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(unserialize($returndata));
```

service.php code

```
$temp = unserialize($_POST['data']);
echo serialize($temp);
```